# what is meaning of thoroughly in "here is the thoroughly revised and updated, and long-anticipated"

Tags: meaning

The original text is :

> *At long last, here is the **thoroughly** revised and updated, and long-anticipated, third edition of the hugely successful
> The Art of Electronics. Widely accepted as the best single authoritative text and reference on electronic circuit design,
> both analog and digital, the first two editions were translated into eight languages, and sold more than a million copies
> worldwide. The art of electronics is explained by stressing the methods actually used by circuit designers – a combination
> of some basic laws, rules of thumb, and a nonmathematical treatment that encourages understanding why and how a
> circuit works.*

I found "thoroughly" have two meaning at [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-simplified/thoroughly) . One meaning as "VERY MUCH" is "completely, very much", the meaning of "completely" is "in every way or as much as possible" at [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-simplified/completely) , other meaning as "CAREFULLY" is "in a detailed and careful way". It seems that both meanings are appropriate.

So which meaning should I adopt ? "completely" or "carefully" ? Thank you.

Comment: The ***carefully***  sense is just by extension from the true literal meaning ***completely*** (in practice, a ***thorough analysis*** and a ***careful analysis*** would normally be pretty much the same thing anyway; no-one would be interested in differentiating the two). You can identify that literal basic meaning by considering the etymology, whereby ***through*** (end-to-end, from one side to the other) leads to the specific variant ***thorough*** (complete, all the way through, nothing missing).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Based on your description, it seems that the word "completely" is more in line with the intended meaning. I know, thank you.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Isn't that an answer? (If you make it one, I'll upvote it!)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'll also upvote it and accept it. Please make it to a answer, thank you very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Completely *and* carefully! The two senses are strongly related, since if you completely revise something, you must do it carefully (or you will miss something).  Both senses apply here